# Shuriken in Aikido

Tags: aikido, shuriken

During the Hell Dojo times of Ueshiba, he was known to teach shuriken throwing. After a [famous incident](http://www.aikidofaq.com/stories/sensei.html), this stopped.

Is there any records of how this was taught? What style of shuriken was thrown? I assume the long bladed ones but confirmation would be nice.

Comment: [Part of the challenge](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598/82)